# Initialize a Moment with the timezone offset that I created it with

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment and moment-timezone in javascript, and this part of it is one of the most unintuitive API's I've ever seen.

I would expect that:

```
moment("2015-12-14T04:00:00Z").utcOffset()
```

would be a pure function and return the offset included in the argument, which is 0. But instead it implicitly converts it to my local timezone offset (PST), so this returns -480 Why?? I asked what offset the object i just created has, not what offset I'm currently in. It would be like if I wrote an api where calling User.find(123).name() returns your name instead of the name of user 123.

Anyway, I can do

```
moment("2015-12-14T04:00:00Z").tz("utc").utcOffset()
```

But my datetime string is dynamic, so I don't know the timezone.

How can I get the behavior I expected, a Moment in js that is in the timezone offset included in the string i passed in?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `parseZone` to keep the offset as it was passed in.

```
moment.parseZone("2015-12-14T04:00:00Z")
```

As to the "why?" part of your question:

- `moment(...)` is local mode.  Ambiguous input (without offset) is assumed to be local time.  Unambiguous input (with offset) is *adjusted* to local time.
- `moment.utc(...)` is utc mode.  Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC.  Unambiguous input is *adjusted* to UTC.
- `moment.parseZone()` keep the input zone passed in.  If the input is ambiguous, it is the same as local mode.
- `moment.tz(...)` with the moment-timezone plugin can parse input in a specific time zone.

Keep in mind that moment has to contend with a wide variety of inputs.

Also keep in mind that a time zone and a time zone offset are two different things.  An offset of `-08:00` doesn't necessarily mean you are in the US Pacific time zone.

Comment: Yeah, there's probably something I'm not considering or historical baggage or something. Having the basic form moment() be local mode just seems like a weird choice, parseZone() behavior seems much more natural for the default behavior. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: FYI, this topic is actually how I first got involved with moment.js.  See [#611](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/611) and [#887](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/887) for the history.