# How to manage timezone with momentjs

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm digging into a strange behavior with timezone and momentjs.

I just want to parse a date from a string but the moment object takes always the CEST timezone instead of the given one.

If I wrote:

`moment("01 Oct 2015 20:26:33 +0300", 'DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z').format()`

the result with any timezone will be

2015-10-01T19:26:33+02:00

is this a bug or I did something wrong?

Here's a fiddle with an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/L1smp698/6/

Comment: Additional similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282009/634824